# Javascript with knockout.js function override

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js

I have a base viewmodel as follows:

```
var myApp = myApp || {};

myApp.BaseViewModel = function () {
    self = this;
    self.var1 = ko.observable();
    self.messageToSay = Function() {
        alert("in Base view model");
    };
    self.sayMessage = function() {
        self.messageToSay();
    }
};
```

And I have a viewmodel that inherits from BaseViewModel as follows:

```
var myApp = myApp || {};

myApp.HomeViewModel = function() {

   var self = this;
   ko.utils.extend(self. new myApp.BaseviewModel());

   self.messageToSay = Function() {
        alert("in Home view model");
    };

};

var vm = new myApp.HomeViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, vm);
```

The problem is that when I execute vm.sayMessage() is always returns "In base view model" rather than "In Home view model". How do I get the messageToSay() method in the HomeViewModel to override the method in the BaseViewModel()?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you should perform inheritence:

```
myApp.HomeViewModel = function() {

   var self = this;
   myApp.BaseviewModel.apply(self, [/*BaseViewModel constructor args */]);

   self.messageToSay = function() {
        alert("in Home view model");
    };

};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sCKh/)

I hope it helps.